# Multiplying Pandas df by 2 constants which creates 2 dfs

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm new to pandas and currently have a df that looks like this:

```
                  p1        p2        p3        p4
dates                                                 
2019-12-01  0.0000468  0.0000455    0.00004  0.0000323
2019-12-02  0.0000401  0.0000353  0.0000333  0.0000318
```

and another df that looks like this:

```
0    680.068
1    319.932
Name: constantValue, dtype: float64
```

What is the fastest way for me to take the first df, multiply it by each constant and create 2 dfs of the same form as the first but multiplied through for each element?

In terms of efficiency, should I split into 2 dfs or introduce some sort of MultiIndex?

Also the constant number could change, so it could return 3 constants which would result in 3 dfs, 4 constants 4 dfs etc

Any advice is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so you have one DataFrame that you want to multiply it by the values of a a distinct Series (because your constant table looks more like a pandas Series than a DataFrame).

There are no efficiency problem here:

- iterating a Series is fast
- multiplying a DataFrame with a scalar value is fast (the pandas or numpy word is *vectorizable*), *provided the columns datatypes are compatible with the multiplication with a float*.

Here you only have (as much as I can guess) floating point columns and a DatatimeIndex for the `dates` index which will not be affected.

The simplest way IMHO would be to build a list of DataFrames. Assuming the original DataFrame is `df` and the constant is the Series `constants`:

```
df_list = [df * val for val in constants]
```

Comment: So this would output a list of data frames for each multiplication? would it be beneficial to have a multi-index rather than a list of dfs?

Comment: @Bob: No this will output one single dataframe per multiplication. But instead on using 2 distinct variables to name the 2 new dataframes, I propose to store the 2 dataframes in a list. That way, if you add a 3rd row to the constants table, the exact same code will give you a list of 3 dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

you can loop through your constant table
and  create a dynamic dataframe and then multiple it with the constant value

here i assume constant_df as your 2nd dataframe containing constants
you loop through it and column_name is the column you want to use to make it unique

```
for constant_df in constant:
  multi[constant['column_name']] = df # to create unique dataframe
  multi[constant['column_name']].select_dtypes(exclude=['object', 'datetime']) * constant['constant_value_column']
```

i have not tried this code, so if any error occurs let me know

Comment: So i should have constant in a list?